# how to implement Shared_preferences in my own class elegantly on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I created such class to store and update the api address locally. But it doesn't work well. How to add the Shared_preferences in the normal class instead of the flutter state widget? So it would make things clearly.

```
// The Server class
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Server{

  String _listUrl;
  String _itemUrl;

  static String _cache1;
  static String _cache2;

  static final Server _server = new Server._internal();

  factory Server({String listUrl, String itemUrl}) {
    _cache1 = listUrl;
    _cache2 = itemUrl;
    return _server;
  }

  Server._internal() {
    read();
    _listUrl=_cache1??"https://www.sjjg.uk./eat/food-items/";
    _itemUrl=_cache2??"https://www.sjjg.uk/eat/recipe-details/";

  }

  String listUrl()=>_listUrl;
  String itemUrl()=>_listUrl;

  void update({String listUrl, String itemUrl}){

    _listUrl = listUrl??_listUrl;
    _itemUrl = itemUrl??_itemUrl;

    save();
  }

  void read() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _cache1=prefs.getString('_listUrl')??"https://www.sjjg.uk./eat/food-items/";
    _cache2=prefs.getString('_itemUrl')??"https://www.sjjg.uk/eat/recipe-details/";

    // print(_cache1);
    // print(_cache1);
  }
  void save() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString('_listUrl', _listUrl);
    prefs.setString('_itemUrl', _itemUrl);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is your  problem?

Comment: As I mentioned, not my problem. It's a bug from Dart. I got null while using `import 'package:flutter_test_app/server.dart';`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I should not `import 'package:flutter_test_app/server.dart';`

Still difference between it with `import 'server.dart';`